# TYPO3 - HMenu ignores access rule "hide at login" for pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

On my website, I have 3 different HMENU, only one of those work correctly, but the TS is almost the same.

Problem is that I see menu positions that I should not see if I am logged in (FE login). 
I see pages with rule "hide at login", but they are not linked anywhere (shows only root page).

My TypoScript configuration (I see "hide at login" pages when I am logged in):

```
lib.submenu = HMENU
lib.submenu.entryLevel = 1
lib.submenu {

  1 = TMENU
1.wrap = <ul> | </ul>  
1 {
        noBlur = 1
        ACT = 0
}
# Normal  
1.NO {
      wrapItemAndSub  =  <li>|</li>
}
# Active
1.ACT = 1
1.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
1.ACT.ATagParams = class="meny_a"

# Current  
1.CUR = 1
1.CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
1.CUR.ATagParams = class="meny_a"  

# If it has a submenu
1.IFSUB = 1
1.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

2 = TMENU
2.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
2 {
  noBlur = 1
  ACT = 0
}

2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>

2.ACT = 1
2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>

2.CUR = 1
2.CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
2.CUR.ATagParams = class="meny_a"

2.IFSUB = 1
2.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
}
```

TypoScript configuration (works correctly):

```
lib.profilmenu = HMENU
lib.profilmenu.special = directory
lib.profilmenu.special.value = {$pp_homepage_id}
lib.profilmenu {

   1 {
        SPC = 1
        SPC.doNotShowLink = 0
        SPC.doNotLinkIt = 1
        SPC.allWrap = <div class="spacer"> | </div> 
  }  

  1 = TMENU

1.wrap = <ul> | </ul>  
1 {
        noBlur = 1
        ACT = 0
}
# Normal  
1.NO {
      wrapItemAndSub  =  <li>|</li>
}
# Active
1.ACT = 1
1.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
1.ACT.ATagParams = class="meny_a"

# Current  
1.CUR = 1
1.CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
1.CUR.ATagParams = class="meny_a"  

# If it has a submenu
1.IFSUB = 1
1.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
}
```

Submenu and profilmenu shows same pages.

To check it live on my webpage you can go to [> this page <](http://www.newwaveprofile.com/myshkin/kontakt.html)
On the top Menu position "Hitta Medlem", and submenu (gold bar, and on the left site)  position "Våra kataloger" should disappear when you login (use auto-login button on gold submenu ("Välj som startsida" or directly [> this link <](http://www.newwaveprofile.com/index.php?id=203&user=myshkin&pass=myshkin&logintype=login&pid=29))

I would like to add that whole login function works correctly, and hide at login rule for content works fine for me, but not in menu (except gold bar menu "profilmenu").

TYPO3 4.5.15

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong there, but I think the below typoscript may help you (add after your typoscript menu code):

```
[usergroup=*] #checks whether a user is logged in.
lib.profilmenu.excludeUidList = 10,11,12  #list of page-uids to be excluded from menu after login.
[global]
```